# Using different navigation animations on one page in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

So I have this FriendsHeader component that navigates to 2 different components. I want to make it so that when I am clicking between "My Friends" and "Friend Requests" there is no animation, but when clicking on the arrow to the "Responses" page there is an animation. Currently this is working for "My Friends" since I do not have animation disabled on it, but it is not working for the "Friend Requests" to "Responses" screen animation (there is no animation when I want there to be one). Anyone know how I could make this work?

FriendsHeader.js

```
export const FriendsHeader = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const state = useNavigationState((state) => state);

  const isActive = (routeName) => {
    const currentRoute = state.routes[state.index].name;
    return currentRoute === routeName;
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("My Friends")}
        style={isActive("My Friends") ? styles.activeButton : styles.button}
      >
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>My Friends</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Friend Requests")}
        style={
          isActive("Friend Requests") ? styles.activeButton : styles.button
        }
      >
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Friend Requests</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={styles.topRightButton}>
        <Ripple
          rippleColor="#fff"
          rippleOpacity={0.9}
          rippleSize={100}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Responses")}
        >
          <MaterialIcons name="arrow-forward" size={24} color="white" />
        </Ripple>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Routes for App.js

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const leftToRightAnimation = {
  gestureDirection: "horizontal-inverted",
  cardStyleInterpolator: ({ current, layouts }) => {
    return {
      cardStyle: {
        transform: [
          {
            translateX: current.progress.interpolate({
              inputRange: [0, 1],
              outputRange: [-layouts.screen.width, 0],
            }),
          },
        ],
      },
    };
  },
};
<ConversationsProvider>
      <FriendsProvider>
        <ResponsesProvider>
          <ReactionsProvider>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <NavigationContainer>
              <Stack.Navigator
                screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
                initialRouteName="Loading"
              >
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="My Friends"
                  component={MyFriendsScreen}
                  options={leftToRightAnimation}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="Friend Requests"
                  component={FriendRequestsScreen}
                  options={{ animationEnabled: false }}
                />
              </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
          </View>
          </ReactionsProvider>
        </ResponsesProvider>
      </FriendsProvider>
    </ConversationsProvider>
```

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktNPX.png)